# How to calculate stuff in OpenOffice Formula

Tags: openoffice

Is it possible to do a calculation in OpenOffice formula? (It should be able to understand "cdot" as times, "over" as divide, etc.)

**Note:** Not OpenOffice calc, but OpenOffice formula.

Comment: Nope. It's solely for formula authoring.

Comment: If calculation in writer is that what you need - press f2. Also I saw some extensions-calculators for writer. You surely can find them with google.